# python metaclass,type class and the object class

Tags: python, object, inheritance, typeclass, metaclass

I'm having headache trying to understand the cyclic relationship that exit between the `metaclass` type, the `object` class, and the `class` type.

I'm trying to understand how python makes everything an object.is it because everything is an instance of the metaclass type or is it because everything is a subclass of object class.

if its because of being subclass of object class, does that mean if the class object was named class `pyobj`. Would that mean that everything in Python starts with pyobj?

I know objects created by metaclass are types/classes, this types are then used to create other object.

From this:

```
>>> isinstance(type, object)
True
>>> isinstance(object,type)
True
>>> issubclass(object,type)
False
>>> issubclass(type,object)
True
```

Is it safe to say that python creates the class object first using the type metaclass (I'm simplifying the metaclass for brevity).

```
type('object',(),{})
```

which implies class object is a class of class type and it does not inherit any attributes other class.

Then it creates the class type:

```
type('type', (object,),{})
```

implying type class is class of class type and it inherits attributes from the object class.

Then creates the other classes by inheriting from the class object

```
type('dict', (object,), {})  
type('Animal', (object), {})
```

which similar to creating an Animal class as :

```
class Animal:
     pass
```

Does this mean the metaclass used to create the class object is still the one used to create this Animal class or is the metaclass type used by default ?

Which type is being used, is it the metaclass type or the type class that was created after object was created ?

Where does the class type created with the base class object come into play ?

I have also tried to understand what really is going on between the object and the class from all he responses above and in this article http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_types_and_objects/python_types_and_objects.html

I'm still getting confused. What is the relation between this two class in terms of object creation?

Will I ever get this or is it a chicken and egg situation?

Comment: Did you read through [3.3.3. Customizing class creation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation) of the Language reference?

Answer (score 2):

Python's core types really do have a chicken and egg situation going on. `type` inherits from `object`, but `object` is an instance of `type`.

You can't really reason about which of `object` or `type` is defined first in Python, because in regular Python code you could not set up their relationship. The Python interpreter gets to do it by fiddling with the internals before the environment is set up, so it doesn't matter if the types are not completely defined up front.

In your example where you call `type` to create new `object` and `type` types, you're not actually getting objects that are equivalent to the real `type` and `object`, as your new `object` type is an instance of the builtin `type` metaclass, not the hand-made `type` metaclass you create later.

Here's an illustration of roughly how the interpreter goes about it. The code doesn't actually work, since you can't create a new-style class without inheriting from `object`, nor can you reassign a `type` object's `__class__` attribute (to make `object` an instance of `type`). If you could, you could start up your own independent type system!

```
my_object = type('my_object', (), {}) # this doesn't work right, it inherits from object
my_type = type('my_type', (my_object,), {})
my_object.__class__ = my_type     # this doesn't work at all (it will raise an exception)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `type` is a chicken and `object` is an egg then C is the dinosaurs (at least when using the most popular python implementation, Cpython). Cpython speeds up things by using C to produce most common objects. So the circular reference is not an issue, technically the dinosaur laid the chicken egg and birthed the live chicken. If that hurts to think about it, then don't.

Once you're in Python land, considering an `object` as the root of everything is a good starting place. That's what allows us to pass around classes and functions in the following example:

```
def my_func():
    pass

class SimpleClass:
    pass

class MetaClass(type):
    pass

class MetaMadeClass(metaclass=MetaClass):
    pass

for o in (str, 'hello', object, object(), type, SimpleClass, MetaClass, MetaMadeClass, print, my_func):
    print(o)
    print('  ', o.__class__)
    try:
         print('  ', o.__mro__)
    except:
         print('   ---   ')  
    try:
         print('  ', o.__call__)
    except:
         print('   ---   ')  
    print('  ', o.__new__)
    print('  ', o.__init__)
```

Maybe someone can place a table here of the output but I'll summarise the interesting ones.

You'll notice a lot of the results have 'built-in' in their names, that's letting you know your not dealing with pure python objects.

In the example, when an attribute is not found on `'hello'` Python checks `__class__`. It'll then follow `str`'s MRO to return `str.__init__` and `object.__new__`.

Objects that have `__class__` = `type` are called classes. That includes `str`, `object` and even `type` itself! In the example, `Simple.__call__` results in invoking `type.__call__`. It is the methods in `type` that configure an object to pass for an instance of that class e.g. it sets `__class__` to the appropriate value.

I'm not sure if `type` is technically a metaclass because it's C code making Python classes, but it can be subclassed and then you definitely have a python class that makes python classes. It allows you to do extreme things like set `__class__` to something completely different, or not return an instance at all, but extreme approaches require an extremely good reason to do it.

### Side note on Cpython

You might guess correctly that the `int` type is implemented in C for efficiency, but even then low `int`'s are handled differently to high `int`'s. Consider this:

```
for a, b in [(1, 1), (10**100, 10**100)]:
    print(a is b)

# Output:
#     True
#     False
```

Cpython goes ahead and generates instances of low integers and reuses them while larger numbers get made on the fly. The result is the `1`'s are references to the same object while the `10**100`'s are two separate object. Point is, if I can indulge in another science analogy, everyday Python is like Newtonian physics and you're heading into the realm of quantum mechanics. I'm tired now...